# Is every finite graph spatial?

Tags: graph-theory

I know that not every finite graph is planar. But can every finite graph be embedded in R^3? That is my question, and I have never seen it answered anywhere I have read.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding has the statement you are looking for in the introduction. ;)

Comment: In its own way, yes, every finite graph has some quality or some talent... *something* that makes it spatial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every graph can be drawn in $\mathbb R^3$ in such a way that all edges are straight and edges only intersect at vertices of the graph. For more information, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding#Embeddings_of_graphs_into_higher-dimensional_spaces).